# Spring WEB security: list of accessible URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm migrating a WEB-application to Spring Security. Application uses Spring MVC for rendering JSPs, and controller methods are annotated with `@Secured(...)`.

So, at some point after successful login and MVC servlet initialization some Spring internals have this information: what permissions the user has (aka granted authorities), controller URLs and permission set, required for each one of those.

What I want is to dynamically get a list of URLs accessible for the current user to generate a navbar.

Of course, I can override some Spring beans for that, but this approach seems too dirty. So, any suggestions on how to do that, maybe standard solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/453925/106261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [spring security tag lib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/taglibs.html) in the jsp, iterating over the list of controllers URLs

```
<sec:authorize url="/admin">
This content will only be visible to users who are authorized to send requests to the "/admin" URL.
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: This technique will only work with the URL based access rules, but will pay no attention to the fine grained access rules defined by `@Secured at method level.